# Can I shoot down lawless ships?

Tags: elite-dangerous

In Elite: Dangerous 1.3, two new ship statuses were added in addition to "clean" and "wanted": "enemy" and "lawless". Obviously one has a green light to shoot down enemy ships, but what about lawless ships? Can I shoot them too without getting fined? Do I get anything out of shooting them?

Comment: I *think* lawless ships (except Corrupt System Defense) might have a bounty, but not in the current system (so it's like a prompt to KWS them). I'm not positive though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shoot anything with a red name without being fined by the pilot's federation. Lawless, for example, appears in Arrissa's expansion system areas and it is similar to a conflict zone.

Depending on the situation these statuses appear in, you could acquire Merit Points and/or PowerPlay Points(for expansion, control, undermining, and some Powers may even offer prep).

But! If the ship you are attacking is in a different power than you but still in the same major faction (Arissa and Aisling are both Empire), you will *lose* Merit points for attacking an ally.

Comment: So shoot away but still pay attention to who they're working for (since lawless imperial ships are perfectly OK). Got it.